# Finding the coordinates of a plane with two straight lines

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

$$
a =
  \begin{cases}
    x=-2+s       \\
    y=2+s     \\
    z=1-s
  \end{cases}
$$
$$
b =
  \begin{cases}
    x=2p       \\
    y=4+2p     \\
    z=4+3p
  \end{cases}
$$
Find the equasion of the plane in which a and b cross

So first I thought I can just get the vectors of the system and make a system like this:
$$v_{a}=(1,1,-1)
$$
$$
v_{b}=(2,2,3)
$$
and after that make a matrix:
$$[
 \begin{matrix}
  x-1 & y-1 & z+1 \\
  2-1 & 2-1 & 3+1 \\
 \end{matrix}
]$$

But I can't do anything with that after that I thought of a thing we did in class which I did not quite understand:

$$
\lambda (-2+s,2+s,1-s)+\mu (2p,4+2p,4+3p)=0 
$$

But that also doesn't lead me to anywhere what do I have to do in this one ?

Comment: What are the  `coordinates` of a plane?

Comment: no information given about the plane, we have to find the coordinates ourselfves,

Comment: You don't answer my question: what are coordinates, for a *plane*?

Comment: as I said, no information is given, the whole problem is to find the coordinates of the plane

Answer (score 1):

at first we compute the intersection Point of the two given straight lines solve the System
$$2p=-2+s$$
$$4+2p=2+s$$
$$4+3p=1-s$$
from here we get $$p=-1$$ and $$s=0$$
thus we obtain the equation in the form
$$[x,y,z]=[-2,2,1]+s[1,1,-1]+t[2,2,3]$$ with the real numbers $$s,t$$

Comment: what are the coordinates of the plane and from where did s and t come from ?